# When is there a need of jQuery in angular2

Tags: jquery, angular

This might seem a very strange question but I still wanted to know as to when should we use `jQuery` in `angular2`.

This question popped up in my mind because I have read prople quoting that-

> Don't do DOM manipulations with jquery in angular2
>
> Don't use jquery for animation in angular2

and these statements make sense as we have stuff provided for that in Angular2.

So when is there an actual need for jQuery. Can anyone explain with some scenarios to clear the understanding here.

Comment: I think you'll find there's no exact specification. This is too broad of a question for Stack.

Comment: Angular is a Framework which takes care of the render, that's why you should not try to manipulate the DOM on your own with JQuery as example.

Comment: Can you point me in some direction(as in some resource).@kevingreen

Comment: Yes that's why I asked if someone can point to some solid scenarios where stuffs cannot be done with angular and jquery has to come into the picture. @Ploppy

Comment: @AakashThakur I think you'll find there isn't a consensus on using JQuery with Angular. For example Ploppy doesn't think you should use it, I use JQuery to maximize my use of Bootstrap.

Comment: It makes sense. @kevingreen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an exact science when it comes to using various libraries. It comes down to preference and experience.

Angular will handle most of the DOM rendering, making JQuery redundant in a lot of areas. There are still uses for JQuery in an Angular project, but it would be handled case by case.

I have used JQuery with Angular2 to take advantage of some Twitter Bootstrap features that I couldn't quite get right with Angular alone. Animations require JQuery, for example the 'collapse' animation from Bootstrap.

By mixing both JQuery and Angular you can get into crosscutting concern problems.   That means it can become unclear which library is responsible for what functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was kind of confused as there were instances where jQuery and angular both were providing functionality like adding animation and after reading stuffs like mentioned in the question.. +1 and accepted

Comment: @AakashThakur consider carefully if you want to bring JQuery into an Angular project. Angular2 is still pretty new, there will be a whole bunch of libraries that will take care of things JQuery can do.

Comment: Alright. Will keep that in mind. Thanks again.